# How to indent without the two extra spaces at the beginning of code blocks in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, indentation

By default org mode source blocks looks like:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (dcg/add-to-list 'package-archives
                   '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
                   '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
                   '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
  (package-initialize)
  (setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
#+END_SRC
```

Is it possible to configure it to indent without the two beginning spaces like:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(dcg/add-to-list 'package-archives
                 '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
                 '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
                 '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to customize `org-edit-src-content-indentation`. I think by default it is set to 2. I think this is what controls that behavior.

However, if you put `(setq org-src-preserve-indentation t)` in your init file, you will get your desired behaviour, plus indentation will be preserved on export. From the docs for `org-src-preserve-indentation` (notice the reference to  `org-edit-src-content-indentation`):

> If non-nil preserve leading whitespace characters on export. If
>   non-nil leading whitespace characters in source code blocks are
>   preserved on export, and when switching between the org buffer and the
>   language mode edit buffer.  If this variable is nil then, after
>   editing with M-x org-edit-src-code, the minimum (across-lines) number
>   of leading whitespace characters are removed from all lines, and the
>   code block is uniformly indented according to the value of
>   `org-edit-src-content-indentation'

Here is a bit of configuration code that I use to get nice indentation and syntax highlighting in the org buffer, among other things. Feel free to experiment with these settings!

```
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t
    org-src-window-setup 'current-window
    org-src-strip-leading-and-trailing-blank-lines t
    org-src-preserve-indentation t
    org-src-tab-acts-natively t)
```

Comment: I didn't know `org-src-window-setup 'current-window` existed. If we ever meet I owe you your choice of beverage.